# Function to determine three procentual values in relation to each other - Progressbar [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar, bootstrap-5, percentage

I have a problem I can't seem to fix.

I have built a ProgressBar in a symfony application with bootstrap installed.
I'm using the following code to display the bar:

```html
<link href="https://bootswatch.com/5/sketchy/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress">
        <div style="width:100%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-danger" role="progressbar"></div>
        <div style="width:100%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-success" role="progressbar"></div>
        <div style="width:100%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-info" role="progressbar"></div>
    </div>
```

I want to overlap the bars to display three different values.
So for example:

- Bar1 should show 50% progress
- Bar2 should show 75% progress (the 50% from Bar1 + 25% own)
- Bar3 should show 100% progress (the 50% from Bar1 + 25% from Bar2 + 25% own)

So that can be achieved with following configuration:

- Bar1: 200% width
- Bar2: 100% width
- Bar3: 100% width

```html
<link href="https://bootswatch.com/5/sketchy/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress">
        <div style="width:200%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-danger" role="progressbar"></div>
        <div style="width:100%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-success" role="progressbar"></div>
        <div style="width:100%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-info" role="progressbar"></div>
    </div>
```

But how would I for example display the following:

- Bar1: 30% progress
- Bar2: 70% progress
- Bar3: 100% progress

I need a function to determine the width of the three bars to show my wanted values.
Then I could add the value for width via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("red").style.width = "30%";
document.getElementById("green").style.width = "70%";
document.getElementById("blue").style.width = "100%";
```

```html
<link href="https://bootswatch.com/5/sketchy/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress">
    <div id="red" style="width:100%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-danger" role="progressbar"></div>
    <div id="green" style="width:100%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-success" role="progressbar"></div>
    <div id="blue" style="width:100%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-info" role="progressbar"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Something like ??

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! I think I explained it a bit wrong. I want the First Bar to make up 30% of the whole bar, the second Bar should make up 70% of the whole bar and the last bar should make up 100% of the whole bar.

Comment: try now please!

Answer (score 0):

The following **setWidth()** function will automatically change the width. Just pass your wanted values as arguments. You don't need to do anything. Just call this function like this => **setWidth(30, 70, 100)**

```js
function setWidth(...arg) {
  let widths = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.progress>div'))
    .forEach((el, i) => el.style.width = (arg[i] - (arg[i - 1] ? arg[i - 1] : 0)) + "%")
}
setWidth(30, 70, 100)
```

```html
<link href="https://bootswatch.com/5/sketchy/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="progress">
  <div style="width:100%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-danger" role="progressbar"></div>
  <div style="width:100%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-success" role="progressbar"></div>
  <div style="width:100%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-info" role="progressbar"></div>
</div>
```